# How do I change the author of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have made a custom post type and need to be able to create posts and assign them to authors. It is easy to do this with posts as you can go to the bulk edit screen and immediately change the author. However, when I try to do this with my custom post type the author box is not there. How do I add the functionality to change the author of my custom post type?

EDIT: I found a solution, see answer below.

Comment: which one, you should tick answer which helped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the edit author attribute is not added by default in for custom post types. To add the author attribute the following code is required:

```
function allowAuthorEditing()
{
  add_post_type_support( 'mytype', 'author' );
}

add_action('init','allowAuthorEditing');
```

Comment: Why don't you just add this when you register your custom post type.

Comment: @BrianFegter - Ideally, it's best to add it when the post type is first registered. However, this approach allows you to add author support to custom post types that you don't have full control over, such as third-party plugins.

Answer (score 27):

in Custom Post Type register arguments array use this

```
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'author'),
```

This will activate author box on the edit screen. After registering author to cpt you need to activate author from edit screen option ( top of the edit screen where you can enable/disable all metabox ) to display authorbox on the edit screen.

Comment: For some reason adding 'author' doesn't change anything in my CPT edit page. And it has something to do with the capabilities of the CTP.

Comment: @Floris Well, that is a different scenario. In that case, you may have to set capabilities for the author or role for the CPT.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Screen Options in the top right corner and check the box that says Author. It will then display the Author meta box. This is possibly the worst user experience in WordPress. It confuses so many people.

Comment: @fdsa What does that mean?

Comment: Referring to answer below, expected 'author' attribute to be by default.

Comment: @fdsa Gotcha! You can add that to the capabilities array.